# Twitter Embedded Timeline Background Colour

Tags: css, iframe, twitter, embed

Using the following twitter embed method (https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines) specifically using the grid layout, is there a way to control background colour?

The issue in context: http://bitly.com/2aFUuhj

The style I would love to update is within a class "GridLayoutTextOnlyTweet" but this is inside an iFrame.

Answer (score 12):

If your using the new Twitter embed from https://publish.twitter.com you can just add `data-chrome="transparent"` to make the background transparent, then you could just have a wrapper element with a background color set.

To the code block

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" data-chrome="transparent" data-link-color="#ffcc00" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow">Tweets by StackOverflow</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Other options available are:

```
data-chrome="transparent nofooter noborders noheader noscrollbar"
```

**Documentation:**

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview

Answer (score 8):

Nice answers but then I did this and the dark theme instantly worked for me

```
data-theme="dark"
```

Check out this link for references
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-parameter-reference

Comment: This questions was asked a number of years ago. There may well be better answers at this point in time.

Comment: I wish there was a way to set it to "auto" and have it follow `prefers-color-scheme`. I couldn't find any clean way of getting the styling to switch automatically, especially since you can't get prefersColorScheme value from JS it seems. The best solution I've come up with is to render both light and dark, and swap which one is shown with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
.GridLayoutTextOnlyTweet {
  background: red;
}
```

It shouldn't matter that it's in an iframe. You may need to add `!important` to override default styles, but try without first.

Comment: Tried with !important and it didn't work. The iFrame is essentially foreign content so I can't manipulate it via pure css. Not sure if there is some kind of Javascript hook (or even a Twitter option somewhere) that I can tweek but after Googleing I can't find one.

Comment: It's not about the iframe, it's about cross-domain security.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.twitter-timeline {
  /* Buttonish */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 30px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f8f8f8 url("") 8px 8px no-repeat;
  background-size: 1em 1em;

  /* Text */
  font: normal 12px/18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Reference : https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/css

Answer (score -1):

Right, this is how I solved it. Place it after the twitter embed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var hideTwitterAttempts = 0;
function hideTwitterBoxElements() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        if ( $('[id*=twitter]').length ) {
        $('[id*=twitter]').each( function(){
            var ibody = $(this).contents().find( 'body' );
            if ( ibody.find( '.grid-Widget' ).length ) {
            ibody.find( '.GridLayoutTextOnlyTweet' ).css( 'background-color', '#1e73be' );
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        }
        hideTwitterAttempts++;
        if ( hideTwitterAttempts < 3 ) {
            hideTwitterBoxElements();
        }
    }, 1500);
}
// somewhere in your code after html page load
hideTwitterBoxElements();
</script>
```

Comment: Using setTimeout is totally unpredictable, what if the user has a slow connection and it takes 2 seconds?

Comment: Agreed it's not ideal. I'm open to a better solution if you have one?